# BrowserField or CustomControls? What is the best to use when submitting and fetching data from web?

Tags: blackberry, custom-application

I am unable to decide whether what to use for my blackberry application.

I am developing an application for Blackberry Device.  This application send and recieves data from website.

Thats the only functionality.

I wanted to know what the best approach to go with.

Shall i use BrowserField and display html in the application??
OR
Shall i develop the custom controls and update the UI with the data fetched from the web??

Please Suggest, advice.

thanks
SIA

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change html, and html is simple enough, it's better to use BrowserField. You will be able to natively represent text and images in html formatting. Even if you go offline you can init it with stored html. Also, you can extract a part of response and use it with BrowserField.

On the other hand, if custom formatting or interactivity is needed, its better to use RIM UI controls.